# The only compact closed surfaces with Euler characteristic 0 are the Klein bottle and torus proof sketch?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I've been on a topology kick, and I recently read on [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerCharacteristic.html) that

- The only compact closed surfaces with Euler characteristic 0 are the Klein bottle and torus.

However, the [reference provided](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0792342933) stated it without proof. What makes these two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the only two surfaces satisfying these given criteria? I suppose I'm not looking for a whole proof (although I would love to see one), only a sketch of one and references to further reading on the subject.

Comment: This is just about as easy to prove as the general classification of surfaces, which, if you google that phrase, you will find lots of notes with the basic proof.

Comment: You say "these two surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$" but be careful: the Klein bottle *cannot* be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, only orientable surfaces can.

Comment: What about the möbius band? It is embeddable in $\mathbb R ^3$ but not orientable.

Comment: I guess I should be more specific: out of all the *closed* surfaces, only the orientable ones embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I have read your comment and I see why this must be true. Only a torus with genus 1 and the connected sum of two real projective planes (that is, a klein bottle) could be closed and compact. Thanks for your help! If you elaborated just a little I would definitely accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the classification of surfaces and the formula $\chi(M \# N) = \chi(M) + \chi(N) - 2$ (valid for arbitrary connected sum of surfaces) then this follows immediately, as $\Sigma_g = \#^g T^2$ has $\chi(\Sigma_g) = 2 - 2g$, and $N_g = \#^g \Bbb{RP}^2$ has $\chi(N_g) = 2 - g$. Because all closed surfaces are diffeomorphic to exactly one of these, and $N_2 = K$, one concludes.

In fact it is not hard to prove the entire classification theorem if you know it for things with Euler characteristic zero by an inductive argument that shows you can safely add/remove handles. (Normally one might reduce it to classifying simply connected surfaces but there's no real additional difficulty caused by stopping at genus 1)